# PHP sessions with forms not working properly

Tags: php, forms, session

I am trying to understand how to use PHP sessions as I need to implement them on another website I am making. Anyway I have made a very basic form with 3 questions on it and when you answer a question and then leave the webpage, it remembers what question you were on before.

The sessions part works, the problem is that the questions are shown twice and when you go to the next question, the previous answer is shown below, if you want to see what I mean go to [Simple Form Sessions](http://s504518.brunelweb.net/SessionButtons.php)

Does anyone know how I can change it so that it only shows 1 question at a time and the sessions still work, at the moment if I take out all the sessions code, it works properly. Here is all the code I have got so far.

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(2592000); //Sets cookie to last for 30 days
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> Using Sessions with Buttons </title>
</head>
<body>
<p> This is the start</p>
<form method='POST' action='SessionButtons.php'>
<input type='submit' name='start' value='start' />
</form>

<?php
$q1 = 'This is question 1';
$q2 = 'This is the second question';
$q3 = 'This is question, number 3';

$answer1 = "This is the first answer";
$answer2 = "This is the answer to the second question";
$answer3 = "Third answer, this is ";
$answer4 = "This is the mighty fourth answer";

$start = "<form method='POST' action='SessionButtons.php'>
<input type='submit' name='yes1' value='yes' />
<input type='submit' name='no1' value='no' />
</form>";

$form1 = "<form method='POST' action='SessionButtons.php'>
<input type='submit' name='yes2' value='yes' />
<input type='submit' name='no2' value='no' />
</form>";

$form2 = "<form method='POST' action='SessionButtons.php'>
<input type='submit' name='yes3' value='yes' />
<input type='submit' name='no3' value='no' />
</form>";

if (!isset($_POST['start'])){
if (isset($_SESSION['question'])){
echo $_SESSION['question'];
echo $_SESSION['form'];
}

} //If start button has been pressed, display questions
else
{
echo $q1;
echo $start;
}

if ($_POST['yes1']){
echo $q2;
echo $form1;
$_SESSION['question'] = $q2;
$_SESSION['form'] = $form1;
}

if ($_POST['no1']){
echo $q3;
echo $form2;
$_SESSION['question'] = $q3;
$_SESSION['form'] = $form2;
}

if ($_POST['yes2']){
echo $answer1;
$_SESSION['answer'] = $answer1;
}

if ($_POST['no2']){
echo $answer2;
$_SESSION['answer'] = $answer2;
}

if ($_POST['yes3']){
echo $answer3;
$_SESSION['answer'] = $answer3;
}

if ($_POST['no3']){
echo $answer4;
$_SESSION['answer'] = $answer4;
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just had to take part of your codes to do some explanation

```
if (!isset($_POST['start'])){
if (isset($_SESSION['question']) && $_POST['yes1'] && $_POST['no1']){
echo $_SESSION['question'];
echo $_SESSION['form'];
}

} //If start button has been pressed, display questions
else
{
echo $q1;
echo $start;
}

if ($_POST['yes1']){
echo $q2;
echo $form1;
$_SESSION['question'] = $q2;
$_SESSION['form'] = $form1;
}
```

re-adjusted my code to skip the second if statement if you've got a question existing. try it this way.

Comment: Removing the echoes from the first if statement does get rid of the repeated questions problem, but when you close the page and re-open it , it no longer remembers what question you were on.

Comment: Still not working, as $_POST resets every time you re-load the page(close it and open it again).

Comment: try to clear the sessions before passing it e.g $_SESSION['question'] = ' ';

Comment: take out the && $_POST['yes1'] && $_POST['no1'])

Comment: Still no luck, I didn't think it would be this hard, I think I'm just going to give up... (sigh)